# extract javascript table that is hidden on page source via VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, extract

I want to extract table from a page that created by javascript and it's elements are not shown in page source. It is the page ([Link](http://www.iafi.ir/%DA%AF%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%AA/%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B2%D8%B4-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C-%D9%87%D8%A7-%D9%88-%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%AF-%D9%87%D8%A7)).

In Firefox I can find hidden part of source via "View selection source". But VBA can't access to hidden elements:

```
    <div class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer" id="arzeshdarayi_wrapper"><div class="dt-buttons"><a href="#" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="dt-button buttons-copy buttons-html5"><span>Copy</span></a><a href="#" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="dt-button buttons-excel buttons-html5"><span>Excel</span></a><a href="#" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="dt-button buttons-print"><span>Print</span></a></div><div class="dataTables_filter" id="arzeshdarayi_filter"><label><input aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" placeholder="جستجو" class="" type="search"></label></div><table style="width: 100%;" aria-describedby="arzeshdarayi_info" role="grid" id="arzeshdarayi" class="display dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row"><th aria-label="زمان : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 36px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting">زمان </th><th aria-sort="descending" aria-label="تاریخ: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 75px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting_desc">تاریخ</th><th aria-label="قیمت صدور: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 63px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting">قیمت صدور</th><th aria-label="قیمت ابطال خالص ارزش روز    : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 82px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting">قیمت ابطال خالص ارزش روز    </th><th aria-label="خالص ارزش آماری    : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 70px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting">خالص ارزش آماری </th><th aria-label="تفاوت مبلغ ارزش آماری با خالص ارزش روز : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 82px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting">تفاوت مبلغ ارزش آماری با خالص ارزش روز  </th><th aria-label="تفاوت درصد ارزش آماری با خالص ارزش روز : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 88px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting">تفاوت درصد ارزش آماری با خالص ارزش روز  </th><th aria-label="تعداد واحدهای صادرشده امروز    : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 73px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting">تعداد واحدهای صادرشده امروز </th><th aria-label="تعداد واحدهای صادر شده تاامروز : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 93px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting">تعداد واحدهای صادر شده تاامروز  </th><th aria-label="تعداد واحدهای ابطال شده امروز      : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 74px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting">تعداد واحدهای ابطال شده امروز       </th><th aria-label="تعداد واحدهای ابطال شده تا امروز   : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 88px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting">تعداد واحدهای ابطال شده تا امروز    </th><th aria-label="تعداد واحد سرمایه‌گذاری نزد سرمایه‌گذار    : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 95px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting">تعداد واحد سرمایه‌گذاری نزد سرمایه‌گذار </th><th aria-label="كل خالص ارزش دارائيها: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 118px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" tabindex="0" class="sorting">كل خالص ارزش دارائيها</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr class="odd" role="row"><td>12:46</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/15</td><td>1,012,967</td><td>1,011,507</td><td>1,009,098</td><td>2409</td><td>0.24%</td><td>0</td><td>11,524,203</td><td>0</td><td>4,953,477</td><td>6,571,726</td><td>6,647,351,262,746</td></tr><tr class="even" role="row"><td>12:40</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/14</td><td>1,012,333</td><td>1,010,883</td><td>1,008,473</td><td>2410</td><td>0.24%</td><td>77959</td><td>11,524,203</td><td>5143</td><td>4,953,477</td><td>6,571,726</td><td>6,643,244,452,033</td></tr><tr class="odd" role="row"><td>13:12</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/13</td><td>1,011,819</td><td>1,010,362</td><td>1,007,927</td><td>2435</td><td>0.24%</td><td>171728</td><td>11,446,244</td><td>14069</td><td>4,948,334</td><td>6,498,910</td><td>6,566,254,645,887</td></tr><tr class="even" role="row"><td>11:14</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/12</td><td>1,011,267</td><td>1,009,782</td><td>1,007,298</td><td>2484</td><td>0.25%</td><td>62780</td><td>11,274,516</td><td>21849</td><td>4,934,265</td><td>6,341,251</td><td>6,403,285,129,644</td></tr><tr class="odd" role="row"><td>11:49</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/11</td><td>1,010,690</td><td>1,009,205</td><td>1,006,699</td><td>2506</td><td>0.25%</td><td>39550</td><td>11,211,736</td><td>35114</td><td>4,912,416</td><td>6,300,320</td><td>6,358,313,227,919</td></tr><tr class="even" role="row"><td>11:07</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/10</td><td>1,010,021</td><td>1,008,623</td><td>1,006,113</td><td>2510</td><td>0.25%</td><td>50967</td><td>11,172,186</td><td>126252</td><td>4,877,302</td><td>6,295,884</td><td>6,350,169,723,202</td></tr><tr class="odd" role="row"><td>12:36</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/09</td><td>1,009,435</td><td>1,008,056</td><td>1,005,584</td><td>2472</td><td>0.25%</td><td>17254</td><td>11,121,219</td><td>7092</td><td>4,751,050</td><td>6,371,169</td><td>6,422,499,283,915</td></tr><tr class="even" role="row"><td>15:07</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/08</td><td>1,008,734</td><td>1,007,358</td><td>1,004,882</td><td>2476</td><td>0.25%</td><td>0</td><td>11,103,965</td><td>0</td><td>4,743,958</td><td>6,361,007</td><td>6,407,808,590,653</td></tr><tr class="odd" role="row"><td>15:00</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/07</td><td>1,008,215</td><td>1,006,851</td><td>1,004,375</td><td>2476</td><td>0.25%</td><td>50208</td><td>11,103,965</td><td>29158</td><td>4,743,958</td><td>6,361,007</td><td>6,404,584,654,430</td></tr><tr class="even" role="row"><td>13:49</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/06</td><td>1,007,682</td><td>1,006,326</td><td>1,003,842</td><td>2484</td><td>0.25%</td><td>196263</td><td>11,053,757</td><td>26576</td><td>4,714,800</td><td>6,339,957</td><td>6,380,065,439,986</td></tr><tr class="odd" role="row"><td>13:52</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/05</td><td>1,007,102</td><td>1,005,724</td><td>1,003,179</td><td>2545</td><td>0.25%</td><td>98424</td><td>10,857,494</td><td>24918</td><td>4,688,224</td><td>6,170,270</td><td>6,205,583,745,026</td></tr><tr class="even" role="row"><td>13:57</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/04</td><td>1,006,507</td><td>1,005,293</td><td>1,002,692</td><td>2601</td><td>0.26%</td><td>55056</td><td>10,759,070</td><td>19459</td><td>4,663,306</td><td>6,096,764</td><td>6,129,032,475,294</td></tr><tr class="odd" role="row"><td>13:18</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/03</td><td>1,005,818</td><td>1,004,597</td><td>1,002,057</td><td>2540</td><td>0.25%</td><td>96499</td><td>10,704,014</td><td>155772</td><td>4,643,847</td><td>6,061,167</td><td>6,089,028,779,015</td></tr><tr class="even" role="row"><td>13:57</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/02</td><td>1,005,237</td><td>1,004,028</td><td>1,001,431</td><td>2597</td><td>0.26%</td><td>2721</td><td>10,607,515</td><td>788</td><td>4,488,075</td><td>6,120,440</td><td>6,145,088,189,758</td></tr><tr class="odd" role="row"><td>14:00</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/10/01</td><td>1,004,652</td><td>1,003,456</td><td>1,000,869</td><td>2587</td><td>0.26%</td><td>0</td><td>10,604,794</td><td>0</td><td>4,487,287</td><td>6,118,507</td><td>6,139,652,390,252</td></tr><tr class="even" role="row"><td>13:56</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/09/30</td><td>1,004,105</td><td>1,002,916</td><td>1,000,330</td><td>2586</td><td>0.26%</td><td>191603</td><td>10,604,794</td><td>9080</td><td>4,487,287</td><td>6,118,507</td><td>6,136,353,083,234</td></tr><tr class="odd" role="row"><td>13:51</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/09/29</td><td>1,003,514</td><td>1,002,297</td><td>999,632</td><td>2665</td><td>0.27%</td><td>103340</td><td>10,413,191</td><td>21231</td><td>4,478,207</td><td>5,935,984</td><td>5,949,621,352,682</td></tr><tr class="even" role="row"><td>12:54</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/09/28</td><td>1,002,923</td><td>1,001,735</td><td>999,043</td><td>2692</td><td>0.27%</td><td>289038</td><td>10,309,851</td><td>10684</td><td>4,456,976</td><td>5,853,875</td><td>5,864,030,526,174</td></tr><tr class="odd" role="row"><td>13:01</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/09/27</td><td>1,002,139</td><td>1,001,151</td><td>1,001,151</td><td>0</td><td>0.00%</td><td>124135</td><td>10,020,813</td><td>23504</td><td>4,446,292</td><td>5,575,521</td><td>5,581,939,275,757</td></tr><tr class="even" role="row"><td>12:16</td><td class="sorting_1">1396/09/26</td><td>1,001,571</td><td>1,000,575</td><td>1,000,575</td><td>0</td><td>0.00%</td><td>40709</td><td>9,896,678</td><td>78930</td><td>4,422,788</td><td>5,474,890</td><td>5,478,036,347,324</td></tr></tbody>
</table><div aria-live="polite" role="status" id="arzeshdarayi_info" class="dataTables_info">نمایش 1 تا 20 از تعداد 2,144 </div><div id="arzeshdarayi_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers"><a id="arzeshdarayi_previous" tabindex="0" data-dt-idx="0" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" class="paginate_button previous disabled">قبلی</a><span><a tabindex="0" data-dt-idx="1" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" class="paginate_button current">1</a><a tabindex="0" data-dt-idx="2" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" class="paginate_button ">2</a><a tabindex="0" data-dt-idx="3" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" class="paginate_button ">3</a><a tabindex="0" data-dt-idx="4" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" class="paginate_button ">4</a><a tabindex="0" data-dt-idx="5" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" class="paginate_button ">5</a><span class="ellipsis">…</span><a tabindex="0" data-dt-idx="6" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" class="paginate_button ">108</a></span><a id="arzeshdarayi_next" tabindex="0" data-dt-idx="7" aria-controls="arzeshdarayi" class="paginate_button next">بعدی</a></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should fetch you the tabular data you are after:

```
Sub TableData()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, elem As Object, trow As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "http://www.iafi.ir/%DA%AF%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%AA/%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B2%D8%B4-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C-%D9%87%D8%A7-%D9%88-%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%AF-%D9%87%D8%A7"
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set html = .document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05") 'this is the trick here to get the data

    Set post = html.getElementById("arzeshdarayi")

    For Each elem In post.Rows
        For Each trow In elem.Cells
            c = c + 1: Cells(r + 1, c) = trow.innerText
        Next trow
        c = 0
        r = r + 1
    Next elem
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: Thanks, It works fine. I wonder there is any way to check the javascript code is ran? Manual wait time may doesn't work if server is slow.

Comment: If the server is slow, manual wait still works because waiting time starts as soon as the page is ready to load it's content. In your chrome address bar type `chrome://settings/content/javascript` and then you will find a toggle radio button to `allow` or `block` javascript content. Block it and reload the page then you will understand whether the page in javascript encrypted or not. As it works, don't miss to tick the grayed out checkbox next to my answer to accept it.